# Can subject line automatically always appear?

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to have the subject line always appear? Too often I forget to change the subject to much embarrassment.

Allow me to clarify: I often have to forward a message on from someone else, but when I hit forward, the subject line is not automatically there and I don't remember I need to change it.

Answer (score 5):

No, sorry. There is no setting in Gmail that will cause the subject line to always be available when replying to/forwarding a message.

Comment: Note to self: write a tampermonkey script

Comment: @SridharSarnobat that was years ago. Any luck?

Comment: I didn't try. But in my defenc after losing my job e I've been doing a lot more tampermonkey scripting to help me with tedious online job applications :))

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about replying to an email, you cannot.  If you're talking about Composing, it *should* appear by default.

Comment: 2021, not anymore :(